# Phonegap installation error npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

windows 7 64 bit.

To install Phonegap I had to install Node.js (v0.10.33) on my system. After this I opened up Windows Powershell and issued the following command like instructed on the Phonegap website:

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Output: (This is the only part of the error)

```
C:\Users\TRUEValentine>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN deprecated deflate-crc32-stream@0.1.2: module has been merged into crc3
2-stream
|


> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\TRUEValentine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phon
egap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io
\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

|


> ws@0.4.31 install C:\Users\TRUEValentine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phon
egap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io
-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm ERR! ws@0.4.31 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.4.31 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\TRUEValentine
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
```

Comment: did you clear the cache `npm cache clear`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add c:\windows\system32 to your PATH